# WPF DataGrid 'Refresh' is not allowed during an AddNew or EditItem transaction mvvm

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

I have the following grid

```
    <DataGrid

        x:Name="TablesDataGrid"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.Row="1"
        ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredModels.View}"
        AlternationCount="2"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        CanUserSortColumns="True"
        CanUserReorderColumns="False"
  CanUserDeleteRows="False"
  CanUserAddRows="False"
  SelectionMode="Extended"
        IsReadOnly="False"
  SelectionUnit="FullRow"
        RowHeight="25"
  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
  ColumnWidth="Auto">
            <DataGrid.Columns >
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Width="*" Binding="{Binding IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"  IsReadOnly="False">
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.CheckAll}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Source Table" Binding="{Binding SourceTableFullName}" Width="4*"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="EDW Schema"  Binding="{Binding SchemaName}" Width="2*"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="EDW Table" Binding="{Binding TableName}" Width="4*"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Binding="{Binding Status}" Width="*"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

and then i have a seachCommand with performs the search on the collectionViewSource FilteredModels in the viewmodel and then calls

```
this.FilteredModels.View.Refresh();
```

when a user checks a few of the checkboxes and sends the grid into editmode and then performs a search we get the following error

```
WPF DataGrid 'Refresh' is not allowed during an AddNew or EditItem transaction
```

is there a way to force the grid out of edit mode when a check box is checked or maybe even when the seach button is clicked or some other fix for this?

thanks!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I know its too late to answer...but for someone who is looking for answer

use cancelEdit or commitEdit method two times in a sequence like this

//for commit

```
this.datagrid_layers.CommitEdit();
this.datagrid_layers.CommitEdit();
```

//for cancel

```
this.datagrid_layers.CancelEdit();
this.datagrid_layers.CancelEdit();
```

Comment: I don't know why using it only once doesn't work, but two times in a sequence works?? any idea...

Comment: It is never too late :D. Your answer saves me a lot of time !!! @Ash: My guess is the datagrid stores two transactions. One for the column and another for the row. You need to commit both before refreshing the collection view.

Comment: For me it's the same, two calls work, one is not enough. Also thanks for the "late" answer, wasn't too late for me too.

Comment: Probably this is the reason: "If a cell is currently in edit mode, the CancelEdit method cancels the cell edit, but not any pending row edits. If a cell is not in edit mode, CancelEdit cancels all pending row edits." [CancelEdit on msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.canceledit?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Instead of calling CommitEdit twice (which is confusing), call: ``CommitEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row, true);``

Answer (score 6):

There is a clean MVVM solution to the problem. First off, your ViewModels must implement `IEditableObject` interface (no-op should be enough). That, however, is not enough since the `DataGrid` will not listen to `IEditableObject.CancelEdit`. 
Another problem is, that neither *ICollectionView* nor *IEditableCollectionView* implement the other one. While only `ICollectionView` can refresh, only `IEditableCollectionView` can commit/cancel. Luckily collection view returned by `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView` implements **both**:

```
// ViewModel.cs
public class ItemVM : IEditableObject, INotifyPropertyChanged { }

public class ModuleVM : INotifyPropertyChanged {
   ICollectionView Items { get; }

   public ModuleVM(ObservableCollection<ItemVM> items) {
      Items = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(items);
   }

   public void RefreshSafely() {
      ((IEditableCollectionView)Items).CancelEdit(); // alterantively, CommitEdit()
      Items.Refresh();
   }
}
```

Or in other words, you can cast `ICollectionView` to `IEditableCollectionView` and call `CancelEdit()` first.

Comment: Thank You. I spent many hours yesterday struggling with this. Every time i changed a checkbox on a datagrid and then tried to open a Dialog, i got the DeferRefresh exception. I'm using MVVM so i couldn't just commitEdit on the datagrid. By combining your example above as follows: 

var Items = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(vm.ThisCustomer.CurrentOrder.OrderDetailsList);                                  
                     ((System.ComponentModel.IEditableCollectionView)Items).CommitEdit();                     Items.Refresh();

The issue was resolved. Nice!!

Answer (score 5):

you should be able to cast the selected item to IEditableObject and call EndEdit on it, or call the grids CancelEdit method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, adapt it to your need.

```
private void CommitEditRefreshViewSafely()
{
    ((IEditableCollectionView)MyCollectionViewList.View).CommitEdit();
    MyCollectionViewList.View.Refresh();
}
```