# DeferRefresh is not allowed during an AddNew or EditItem transaction

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a Window containing 2 DataGrids. And if I click from one specific column in the first DataGrid into any column of the other DataGrid, then I get the error

> DeferRefresh is not allowed during an AddNew or EditItem transaction

What is going wrong here?

The first DataGrid is

```
<DataGrid x:Name="FirstDataGrid"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Parts, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPart, Mode=TwoWay}"
          CellEditEnding="DataGrid_OnCellEditEnding" >
     <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
          <views:ScrollIntoViewBehavior />
     </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
          <DataGrid.Resources>
               <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                   <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="DataGridCell_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"></EventSetter>
               </Style>
          </DataGrid.Resources>
      <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Identifications, Mode=OneWay}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0">
                                            <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding ArticleNumber, Mode=OneWay}" 
                                                        Command="{Binding ElementName=PartDataGrid, Path=DataContext.OpenIdentificationCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" >                                    
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ArticleNumber, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                            </Hyperlink>
                                        </TextBlock>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The second DataGrid does not matter since I can click on any column to produce the error.

Comment: Interesting that you can't duplicate flag bountied questions! This seems to have been asked before here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18281615/deferrefresh-is-not-allowed-during-an-addnew-or-edititem-transaction , and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20204592/wpf-datagrid-refresh-is-not-allowed-during-an-addnew-or-edititem-transaction-m .

Comment: I read these but that did not solve my problem.

Comment: From those posts it looks as if your first Datagrid may have been put into an edit state when you clicked on its column. Can you bind a property to its SelectedItem and (from 2nd link above) 'cast the selected item to IEditableObject and call EndEdit on it, or call the grids CancelEdit method'. Either that or wire a Command up to something like the first DataGrid's LostFocus event to cancel or commit any pending edits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved it by myself.

The column that causes problems is read-only. So why allow an edit mode anyway? That is obviously wrong. I fixed that by adding

```
IsReadOnly="True"
```

to the WPF column definition.