# Filtering large data collections in a ListView C#

Tags: c#, wpf, large-data

I am trying to use a filter field that filters a large list of data, stored in an `ObservableCollection`, based on whether an item contains a string and display the results in a `ListView`.

Currently I am using a converter to achieve this. It works by checking if a target string contains the filter string by using a simple case insensitive compare method.

```
private static bool Contains(string source, string toCheck, StringComparison comp = StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
{
    return source?.IndexOf(toCheck, comp) >= 0;
}
```

This approach seems to work fine for a smaller number of entries (a few hundred). But the data size I am working with can range from 50 thousand to 200 thousand entries.

Is there a way to efficiently filter the list without large performance hits when searching data collections of roughly 200000 entries.

MCVE below.

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="FastFilter.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FastFilter"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Fast Filter" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:FilterConverter x:Key="FilterConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=FilterString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <ListView Grid.Row="1"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Infos}">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource FilterConverter}">
                                <Binding Path="DataContext.FilterString" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}"/>
                                <Binding Path="Text"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <!-- List Box Item Layout -->
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Content="Text:"/>
                            <Label Content="{Binding Text}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**CS**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace FastFilter
{
    public partial class MainWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            for (int i = 0; i < 200000; i++)
            {
                Infos.Add(new ObjectInfo(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private string filterString = string.Empty;
        public string FilterString
        {
            get => filterString;
            set
            {
                filterString = value; 
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<ObjectInfo> infos = new ObservableCollection<ObjectInfo>();
        public ObservableCollection<ObjectInfo> Infos {
            get => infos;
            set {
                infos = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public class ObjectInfo
    {
        public ObjectInfo(string text)
        {
            Text = text;
        }

        public string Text { get; }
    }

    public class FilterConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string filter = (string)values[0];
            string checkStringContains = (string)values[1];

            return !(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(checkStringContains) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter))
                ? Contains(checkStringContains, filter) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed
                : Visibility.Visible;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        private static bool Contains(string source, string toCheck, StringComparison comp = StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        {
            return source?.IndexOf(toCheck, comp) >= 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorting, Grouping, Filtering and selection tracking in WPF is done via a CollectionView. The UI classes will automatically create (and even share) a single CollectionView, but to use it effectively you have to take control of it's creation. Indeed you should aim to expose the CollectionView, rather then the raw ObservableCollection.

Comment: What about using `Hashset<T>.` Contains would be O(1).

Comment: "But the data size I am working with can range from 50 thousand to 200 thousand entries." If you are retrieving that many entries, your base design for DB access is plain wrong. You can not actually show the user more then maybe 100 fields of data and expect him to work with it. If you are doing filtering on that scale, always do it in the DB querry. Do not bulk retreive to then do filtering in the UI. Use paging and whatever else the DBMS supports to not retrieve that much data.

Comment: this could be useful https://github.com/lvaleriu/Virtualization/tree/master/DataVirtualization, it will only load a specified amount of records to be displayed.

Comment: @Christopher Thank you for that information. I will look at redesigning it so the DB handles it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using ICollectionView.

xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBox TextChanged="FilterTextChanged" Text="{Binding Path=FilterString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <ListView 
              x:Name="InfosListView"
              Grid.Row="1"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Infos}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <!-- List Box Item Layout -->
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Content="Text:"/>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Text}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

CS

```
    private void FilterTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateFilter();
    }

    private void UpdateFilter()
    {
        //NOTE: bellow comment only applies to DataGrids.
        //Calling commit or cancel edit twice resolves exceptions when trying to filter the DataGrid.
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20204592/wpf-datagrid-refresh-is-not-allowed-during-an-addnew-or-edititem-transaction-m
        //CommitEdit();
        //CommitEdit();

        ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Infos);
        if (view != null)
        {
            view.Filter = delegate (object item)
            {
                if (item is ObjectInfo objectInfo)
                {
                    return objectInfo.Text.Contains(FilterString);
                }
                return false;
            };
        }
    }
```

Next upgrade would be to add a DispatcherTimer to the textchanged event so that the filter only updates after text has not been enter for about a second, instead of for each character.

Answer (score 0):

For this sort of adhoc query, you have to scan through the entire collection to build up the set of filtered items, so there's not much you can do there.

My suggestion to help with efficiency is not to re-do the filter immediately after each (single character) change to the filter string. Instead, have each change to FilterString (re-)start a timer object with a period of say 1 second, and only actually do the filtering once the timer ticks. Or you could use some kind of buffered reactive extensions construct to achieve the same result.