# Why is a WPF DataGridCell.Content a TextBlock instead of a TextBox after adding a new item programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to copy-paste data from a Excel table into a WPF `DataGrid`. For this I have the following function, which gets called on the `KeyDown` event:

```
private void OnDataGridPasteData(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ((Keyboard.Modifiers != ModifierKeys.Control) || e.Key != Key.V)
        return;

    DataGrid dg = (DataGrid)sender;

    var pastedData = Clipboard.GetText();
    List<string> rowDataCombined = pastedData.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();
    List<string[]> rowData = new List<string[]>();
    foreach (var row in rowDataCombined)
    {
        rowData.Add(row.Split(new string[] { "\t" }, StringSplitOptions.None));
    }

    int initialRowIdx = Math.Max(dg.Items.IndexOf(dg.SelectedItem), 0);
    int initialColIdx = dg.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex;
    int maxColIdx = dg.Columns.Count;
    int maxRowIdx = initialRowIdx + rowData.Count;

    Type sourceType = dg.ItemsSource.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
    var sourceList = (IList)dg.ItemsSource;

    for (int r = initialRowIdx; r < maxRowIdx; r++)
    {
        if(r > dg.Items.Count - 1)
        {
            var newRowObject = Activator.CreateInstance(sourceType);
            sourceList.Add(newRowObject);
        }

        DataGridRow dgRow = GetRowFromDataGrid(dg, r);
        if (dgRow == null)
            continue;

        for (int c = initialColIdx; c < maxColIdx; c++)
        {
            var presenter = FindVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(dgRow);
            // try to get the cell but it may possibly be virtualized
            var cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(c);
            if (cell == null)
            {
                // now try to bring into view and retreive the cell
                dg.ScrollIntoView(dgRow, dg.Columns[c]);
                cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(c);
            }

            if(cell != null)
            {
                cell.Focus();
                if (!dg.BeginEdit()) //abort pasting if editing fails
                {
                    dg.CancelEdit();
                    return;
                }

                if(cell.Content is TextBox tb)
                {
                    tb.Text = rowData[r - initialRowIdx][c - initialColIdx];
                }
                if(!dg.CommitEdit()) // abort pasting if commit fails (e.g. wrong entry type)
                {
                    dg.CancelEdit();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the line `if(cell.Content is TextBox tb)`:

- For existing `DataGridCells` this will be `true`
- For newly added items (line `sourceList.Add(newRowObject);`) this will be false. The content type then is a `TextBlock`
- If I add all the needed rows in a `while` loop in the same manner as above before entering the `for` loops, it will also result to `true`. However, I want to abort the whole operation, if the pasting fails without having the extra rows afterwards.

The `DataGrid` has `AutoGenerateColumns` set to `true`. Generated cells seem to get a `TextBlock` initially as content, which is later changed to a `TextBox`. Question is, what triggers this change, and can I do it manually? Would I break anything, if I simply change the content to a `TextBox` in case it is a `TextBlock`?

Comment: the mode ? Like edit mode. `DataGrid.BeginEdit()` _Invokes the `System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid.BeginEdit` command, which will place the current cell or row into edit mode._

Comment: @NawedNabiZada sorry needed a bit to reply. I will test this immediately :)

Comment: @NawedNabiZada looking at the code, this can't really be it, since I already call `BeginEdit()`

Comment: Yeah I don't know really, this popped in my mind. Usually there in the template you have the TextBlock in normal state/mode while TextBox is provided in edit state/mode

Comment: Yep, DGs editing in code is a pain.

Comment: I see that the DataGridCell has a IsEditing property. have you tried to set that one to  true to see if that triggers the editing state ?

Comment: @NawedNabiZada na, I think I just found the problem. Writing the answer atm...as usual small issue, big efffect.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After searching a while I think I have found the issue. I have set the property `DataGrid.CanUserAddRows` to true by default. After editing the last row, it seems the `DataGrid` is therefore adding an empty row consisting of `TextBlocks` (until the user starts editing in the GUI) after the programmatic edits.

Setting the flag to false at the beginning of my paste function and back to true before returning fixes the problem.

Comment: A sidenote: If any1 is using the function above in the future and wonders, why the bound datacontext in the vm won't update, have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20204592/wpf-datagrid-refresh-is-not-allowed-during-an-addnew-or-edititem-transaction-m)